# Can I to call a method from a variable in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have an example class.

```
class example(object):
    # ...
    def size(self):
        return somevalue
```

How can I get the `size` value by `instance.size` in stead of `instance.size()` without assign an new variable `size`?

Comment: by adding the wrapper `@property` above the method https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you write out some pseudocode that shows what you want to do?

Comment: wrapper -> decorator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should user `@property` decorator
https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html#properties

```
class example(object):
    # ...
    @property
    def size(self):
        return 'somevalue'

example_inst = example()
example_inst.size #'somevalue'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `@property` is definitely more idiomatic, but for the sake of completeness, this is what's going on behind the scenes.

In Python, the `__getattr__` magic method gets called when a field that doesn't exist is requested from an object.

```
class example(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key == "size":
            return somevalue
        else:
            return super().__getattr__(key) # Python 3.x
            # return super(self.__class__, self).__getattr__(key) # Python 2.x
```